# Realm sample code from the docs gives 'io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Dog is not part of the schema for this Realm'

Tags: kotlin, realm

I'm trying to adapt for Kotlin a very simple piece of Java `Realm` code straight from [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started):

```
// Define your model class by extending RealmObject
class Dog : RealmObject() {
   var name: String? = null
   var age: Int = 0

}

class Person : RealmObject() {
   @PrimaryKey
   val id: Long = 0
   val name: String? = null
   val dogs: RealmList<Dog>? = null // Declare one-to-many relationships

}
```

In `onCreate`:

```
    // Initialize Realm (just once per application)
    Realm.init(this);

    val config: RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("default.realm").build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

Then elsewhere I call:

```
var dog = Dog()
dog.name = "Rex"
dog.age = 1

realm.beginTransaction()
var managedDog: Dog = realm.copyToRealm(dog)
val person = realm.createObject(Person::class.java)
person.dogs!!.add(managedDog)
realm.commitTransaction()
```

I'd expect that Rex would be written to the DB (maybe I need to call `executeTransaction` first?) but instead I get the exception:

`io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Dog is not part of the schema for this Realm`

How should I make `Dog` part of my scheme?  Giving it a `@PrimaryKey` and `id` doesn't help.

**UPDATE**: I guess I need to add some schemas as I opened the `default.realm` and it's empty:

[image]

Comment: This probably happened because you didn't add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just saw your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/q/42947367/1390035 so tried to put 
apply plugin: 'realm-android' after the others but I get an error: 
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution.